# Should we upgrade Jasmine and Karma related dependencies too during Angular upgrade?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have upgraded Angular app recently along with Material, but somehow it resulted in more and more test fails.

So, I would like to understand, whether it is a mandatory step to update the versions of jasmine & karma related package dependencies in package.json ? Because as per the version compatibility, we do update the versions of tslib, rxjs, typescript & nodejs etc in the package.json. So does it apply same to Jasmine & Karma?

If yes, how to do that? Will it solve the test case fails issue occurred after angular v15 upgrade? All these tests were passing earlier.

Please provide a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been some testing logic upgrades in `15`, You can find the comprehensive steps on V15 below

[Angular Upgrade Guide V14 -> V15](https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=14.0-15.0)

Have you done the below steps?

> - Update instances of Injector.get() that use an InjectFlags parameter to use an InjectOptions parameter. The InjectFlags parameter of Injector.get() is deprecated in v15. [Read further](https://angular.io/guide/update-to-version-15#v15-dp-02)
> - Update instances of TestBed.inject() that use an InjectFlags parameter to use an InjectOptions parameter. The InjectFlags parameter of TestBed.inject() is deprecated in v15. [Read further](https://angular.io/guide/update-to-version-15#v15-dp-01)

Also check if the correct versions are set for `karma` and `jasmine` below is a stackblitz of a new project using angular 15, the versions should match, if you have a different version of angular 15, then first do `npm i -g  @angular/cli@<<version>>` then do `ng new test`, then check the versions of `karma` and `jasmine` and verify all versions are the same!

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.10",
"@angular/cli": "~15.2.10",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
"jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
"karma": "~6.4.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
"typescript": "~4.9.4"
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-dxzp4c?description=Starter%20project%20for%20Node.js,%20a%20JavaScript%20runtime%20built%20on%20Chrome%27s%20V8%20JavaScript%20engine&file=test%2Fpackage.json&title=node.new%20Starter)

Comment: @ng_dev then validate why the test are failing, if possible try changing the values of the karma and jasmine packages and check if the errors reduce, do trial and error, until you find the root cause!

Comment: @ng_dev Yes, if not needed, we can skip! also did you find out why the test failures increased? did it reduce after changing the versions of karma and jasmine!